# Point on an X Y Plane in a Discrete Random Walk

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, coordinate-systems, random-walk

Consider a point on a plane starting at the origin ($X_0, Y_0$ = $0,0$). At each discrete step, the point moves a distance of one unit in four possible directions, with an equal probability of 1/4 for each possible move. Find E[$X_N^2 + Y_N^2$] for all nonnegative integers N. The hint that is given is that this is a variance problem.

This is where I am so far:
P(left = -1) = 1/4
P(right = +1) = 1/4
P(no step) = 1/2

P(up = +1) = 1/4
P(down = -1) = 1/4
P(no step) = 1/2

For each axis separately, say the X-axis, I'm at the following: E(x) = 0, Var(x) = N/2 after N steps

But how do I go about combining this for two axises?

Comment: Expectation is a linear operation, i.e. $E[X_N^2+Y_N^2] = E[X_N^2] + E[Y_N^2]$.  Does this help you?

Comment: A little. I figured linearity of expectation is needed for this problem, I am just at a loss of where the square comes in and how that relates to variance.

Comment: The variance comes in from how it relates to the first two moments: $\operatorname{Var}(X) = E[X^2] - E[X]^2$.

Comment: Could you explain that little further? How does that variance related to the E that we are trying to calculate? I  am having trouble seeing how the two relate

Answer (score 1):

We can write $X_i = X_{i-1} + Z_i$, $i\in \mathbb N$ where the $Z_i$'s are idd with $P(Z_i = \pm 1) = 1/4$ and $P(Z_i = 0) = 1/2$. Then by iterating back to $X_0$, 
$$
X_N = X_{N-1} + Z_N = X_{N-2} + Z_{N-1} + Z_N = \ldots = \underbrace0_{X_0} + \sum_{i = 1}^N Z_i.
$$
Remember that $E[Z^k] = \sum_n n^k P(Z = n)$ so you should get that 
\begin{align}
E[X_N^2] 
&= 
E[(Z_1 + \ldots + Z_N)(Z_1 + \ldots + Z_N)] 
\\&=
E[Z_1^2+ \ldots + Z_N^2] + \sum_{i = 1;i\ne j}E[Z_iZ_j]
\\&=
E[NZ^2] + 0
\\&= N\cdot 1/2.
\end{align}

Now, $X_i \stackrel d= Y_i$ by symmetry so also $E[Y_N] = 0$ and $E[Y_N^2] = N/2$.

Then by linearity of the expected value,

$$
E[X_N^2+Y_N^2] = E[X_N^2] + E[Y_N^2] = N/2+N/2 = N.
$$

Comment: Woops! You are right. Thank you @ByronSchmuland for noticing my mistake! I edited the answer.